# Vuejs2: How to re-render array computed properties when array changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, render, vuejs2, computed-properties

I have array named List and created computed property computedList for him.
When i update value of array it's not showing in html, but in console i see thar array is updated.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/apokjqxx/69/`
```

What is best way to use computed properties for array?

Maybe is exists way to trigger to re-render computed property?

Comment: Some code would help. Do you have a jsfiddle showing the problem? Computed properties should work just fine and show updated values if the properties they reference update as well

Comment: Code is here https://jsfiddle.net/apokjqxx/69/. Computed propertis working fine for object and not for arrays by default.

Comment: It's a vuejs limitation where it cannot pickup changes if you directly modify the array that way. https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the changes to an array like this: `this.list[1] = 'vueman'`

You have to use `Vue.set` or `vm.$set` as explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) to  trigger state updates in the reactivity system, like follwoing:

```
  this.$set(this.list, 1, 'vueman')
```

see updated fiddler [here](https://jsfiddle.net/apokjqxx/70/).

Comment: Thanks! Works fine. Also i've updated jsfiddle for use multidemensoal array, hope it will helpfull for anyone - https://jsfiddle.net/apokjqxx/73/